# iOS Debug Description of UIView Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

All,

I'm having trouble understanding where the last half of this debugger description output for a UIView Object in iOS.

Here is the Debug output:

```
<myView_inIOS: 0x117f9bbc0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (562 39; 30 30); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x282b47ca0>> iview:[myCustomView @ 0x11995b800 id: 427 hidden myView: {0x117f9bbc0 f: {{562, 39}, {30, 30}} layer: 0x282b47ca0} key: 859b rowOffset: 440 componentNeedsLayout hidden]
```

What are the properties of this UIView object being referenced by the iview: property? I've tried looking at the CALayer, and Subviews but I don't know what that iview:[] array means and how to access it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to access `IView`? If all you want to do is get rid of that extra description string then you can subclass `myView_inIOS`, or what ever that class you are using, and override the description by returning what ever description and details you want in there. If you are not instantiation the class then as Stephen Liu mentioned, you may exchange the description implementation with your own.

If you really need to access `Iview` we need details on what class you have instantiated there, and any links to its documentation.

If the library is static then you might not be able to easily reference/access Iview. And it would probably be hidden for good reason too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to check that weather the "description" function is overwrited by class of "iview" probably inherited from UIView, when you try to debug an objective-c class with po, the console just print out the result of "description" method returned~! if the subclass of UIView does not overwrite "description" function, the default implementation will be printed just as myView_inIOS.

Comment: if  source code of class of 'iview' is not visible, you can hook the function "description" with method_exchangeImplementations and print your own informations

Comment: I can call the "Description" and "DebugDescription" common methods on other UI Objects, ScrollViews, UIImageViews, and UIViews, but in some cases that second class iView doesn't print. Only some objects carry the iView Class with it. My goal is to capture the obj id of the iView id. You are correct the code that is generating and managing the iview class is a compiled framework that dynamically renders UI objects from XML Templates.To me it appears as though the iView Object is apart of both the UIView and the CALayer of the parent object. Almost as though the iView class, its object is linked

Comment: I just can't figure out how to pull that iview array or its object id. I've tried several ObjC runtime library calls, but no luck. Is method_exchangeImplementations more for swizzling the two objects (my visible UI_View, and the iView_)?